# Mode function (python)

Tags: python, function, mode

I tried to write mode function:

```
C=[13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 20]
def mode(x):
  y={}
  for a in x:
    if not a in y:
      y[a]=1 
    else:
      y[a]+=1 
    return [g for g,l in y.items() if l==max(y.values())]
print("The mode  of List is", mod(C))
```

but the output is 13. what is wrong in the code?

Comment: You have an indentation error on your `return` it needs to be shifted to the left. At the moment your return does so after the first iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 2):

indentation problem, should return after completing the for loop:

```
def mode(x):
  y={}
  for a in x:
    if not a in y:
      y[a]=1 
    else:
      y[a]+=1 
  return [g for g,l in y.items() if l==max(y.values())]
print("The mode  of List is", mode(C))
```

just for completion, there is function mode in the statistics library:

```
import statistics
C=[13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 20]
statistics.mode(C)
```

Comment: Ah, the early return